# How to delete rails and others logs using cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, cron

I am working on huge project where we have many logs which keeps updating continuously, We have following files:

cron.log, cron_error.log,  newrelic_agent.log,  production.log  sidekiq.log,     unicorn.log

I want to know how to delete these file with the help of cron job almost daily basic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a cron that run daily and remove the content from file. You should not delete those files as that are necessary to run your app smoothly.

Your cron should be like

```
00 11 * * * echo '' > /path/to/dir/production.log; echo '' > /path/to/dir/sidekiq.log;
```

Dont forget to adjust time and path to your files.

Moreover I would suggest to use something like [logrotate](https://serversforhackers.com/managing-logs-with-logrotate) to keep previous days logs. For production app, you must get in situation where you need to keep logs to track down certain issues with application.